# If column A equals a certain value, generate a value in column B. Check each cell in column A --> Generate a value in each cell in column B

Tags: excel, vba

I have a very simple question that I can't find the answer to.

Here is an example of what I'd like to do:

- Sample Data

[image]

- If a row in column A = 'Sandwiches', I would like column B to display 'It's a Sandwich'
- If a row in column A = 'Wraps', I would like column B to display 'It's a Wrap'
- etc. etc.

So far, I am able to do this for the first row. I'm having trouble creating a for loop to loop through all the available cells.

Here is what I have so far (was thinking of adding Else If statements for different values later):

Current If Statement

[image]

Comment: No pictures of code here. Please [edit] your question with the code as text.

Comment: Use a lookup table and Vlookup.

Comment: If you want vba, first find the [last row with data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba) then you would do a simple for: `For i = 2 to lastrow`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you prefer the use of VBA code instead a formule as Ozgun Senyuva suggested. You can try this code:

```
Sub Food_and_thing()
  Dim myLine As Double
  Dim myFood As String
  Set SavedData = Sheets("SavedData")
  myLine = 2
  
  With SavedData
    Do While .Cells(myLine, 1) <> "" 'Assume that Category is in column A, and Generated Asset Name is in column B
      myFood = " an other thing"
      If .Cells(myLine, 1) = "Sandwiches" Then
         myFood = " a Sandwich"
      ElseIf .Cells(myLine, 1) = "Wraps" Then
         myFood = " a Wrap"
      ElseIf .Cells(myLine, 1) = "Salads" Then
        myFood = " a salad"
      End If
      .Cells(myLine, 2) = "It's" & myFood
      myLine = myLine + 1
    Loop
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution Mohamad. The logic for saying "It's another thing" populates, but it doesn't generate asset names from the If, else if statements

Comment: Sorry, There were two errors: " Wraps" instead "Wraps" and myFood=" an other thing was outside of the loop. I correct the code above and tested it, it's working..

Comment: Awesome, this works. Thanks, Mohamad!

Comment: Akash! I'm glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Akash you do not need to write vba codes for this.  You may use a lookup table and apply Vlookup formula as @BigBen said.

Apart from this, this formula can make you happy if you ignore some spelling errors.  Enter this in cell B2 and paste along the way down.

`="It's " & A2`

Comment: Thank you for your help, Ozgun. I'm looking to build upon a macro and would like to write the logic in VBA. This is a start though, I will keep this solution in mind.